# Image double to binary in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

Good morning,

I have a question about how can I convert a satellital image to binary numbers. The format of each band is a matrix of type double (655x639 length) and numbers are like these: 204080, 200, etc. I want to convert it to a binary format . So, for example:

20480 = 101000000000000
200 = 11001000

I've tried with the "dec2bin" command but it creates a matrix with different length (418545x8 char) and I think, it doesn't work properly (I want the same size). Furthermore, I've tried to change the format into uint16 or uint8, among others. How can I do it?

Greetings,

Comment: Using dec2dbin you do get a correct binary representation of your inputs. Not sure I understand the `different length` issue... You can use `dec2bin` with a second argument specifying the number of bits you want to have returned, e.g. `dec2bin(200,16) = 0000000011001000`, if you'd like to have at least 16 bits returned.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you tell us what you want to do with the binary numbers - it's rarely needed explicitly convert numbers to theirs binary representation.

Comment: Hi Sebastian! Thank you so much for your quickly reply. I need to transform that values because I need to know information of two values from the binary value (it is a cloud mask band and the information is on binary code). With your code (200,16) it workes fine but my doubt is because I want to get (I don't know if it's possible) the same matrix length (655x639) with all the binary numbers, just to check it. For example, when I apply your code, I get a 418545x16 char, not 655x639 (and I can't watch it because it's so big). I hope I explained it better!

Answer (score 1):

I have a question for you: How would you represent the binary number for each pixel in your image?
Initially, each pixel is represented by a *single* floating point number, that is 655*639*1 floats. Converting to `uint16` or `uint8` does not change the fact that each pixel is stil represented by a *single* number.
However, when you conver to binary *string* using `dec2bin` you wish to represent each pixel using *several* (8 or 16) binary digits. Thus, your result is now of size 418,545-by-8 (note that 418,545 = 655 * 639 ).
What you can do is `reshape` the result to use third dimension to store the binary vectors per-pixel

```
sz = size(myDoubleIm);
binIm = dec2bin( uint16(myDoubleIm) ); % convert to 16 bit
binIm = reshape( binIm, sz(1), sz(2), [] ); % convert to 3D
```

Comment: Hi Shai! As I told to Sebastian, this information is just to check it because it's a cloud mask and the information that I need are on the binary code (I don't want to represent or something like that). I've tried your code and I get a result of 0 and 1 to binary image. I'm going to try to mix with the other reply! Thank you so much!